# Angularjs watch when user type comma in input text

Tags: javascript, angularjs

All is in the question, I want to watch for the input text while user is typing and when he types a comma the Input get validated instead of `ng-click="action()"`
I want something like Comma-Typed="action()", I tried with ng-change , scope.watch() with no lack ..

what I have so far :

```
<input id="tagInsert" type="text" name="newTag" ng-model="newTag" ng-model-options="{debounce: 100}" typeahead="tag for tag in getTags($viewValue)" class="form-control" typeahead-loading="loadingTags" ng-keydown="addInterestOnEvent($event)" ng-disabled="interestLimit" autocomplete="off" ng-change="alert('stuff')" />
```

Controller :

```
$scope.$watch('newTag', function(val) {
             if (val.keyCode == 188) { // KeyCode For comma is 188
             alert('comma added');
             action();
           }
    });
```

I have also tried with ng-keydown :

```
$scope.addInterestOnEvent = function (event) {
        if (event.which !== 188) return;
        event.preventDefault();
        $scope.addInterest();
    };
```

this is doesn't work.

**EDIT**

It does work with `ng-keydown="action()"` it was me forgetting to restart the server.

Comment: Create very simple directive `commaTyped`.

Answer (score 0):

your $watch logic is incorrect.$watch is used to look for changes in model value . Please refer [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) .All $watch does is registers a callback when a expression changes.

```
$scope.$watch('newTag', function(nv,ov) {
       if (nv!==ov ){

         action();

    }
});
```

In your case you will have to write a directive and look for `,`